# Prove this statement

Tags: predicate-logic

Let's say we have some predicate $ P $, then how does one prove the following statement?

$$\forall x \forall y ((x=y \wedge P (x))\Rightarrow P (y)) $$

Comment: This follows from the axioms of first-order logic, it has nothing to do with $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Asaf, changed the question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Direct Proof

As $x=y$, $\forall x ((x=x \wedge P (x))\Rightarrow P (x))$ by substitution, and $\forall x ((x=x \wedge P (x))\Rightarrow P (x))$ because by [reflexitivity of equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_%28mathematics%29#Some_basic_logical_properties_of_equality), $\forall x (P (x)\Rightarrow P (x))$ by [conjunction elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplification), and the result is true.

### Proof by Contradiction

Let's try to [prove by contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prove_by_contradiction), and suppose that's false.

If so, $\exists x \exists y ((x=y \wedge P (x))\not\Rightarrow P (y))$ (read out loud and you'll see it is obvious).

So $\exists x ((x=x \wedge P (x))\not\Rightarrow P (x))$, and $\exists x (P (x)\not\Rightarrow P (x))$  which is obviously a contradiction.

### Proof through a Truth Table

$x=y$ is a statement, so $(0; 1)$ and $(1; 0)$ values, respectivly, for $x$ and $y$, don't apply.

```
P(x) P(y)  → (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional)
0    0     1
1    1     1
```

(where $1$ is true and $0$ is false)

Therefore $\forall x \forall y ((x=y \wedge P (x))\Rightarrow P (y))$ follows $\forall x \forall y ((x=y \wedge 1)\Rightarrow 1)$ and $1 \Rightarrow 1$, $1$, and $1$ is true-

Comment: As this is a short answer, I'll add a direct proof and a table-based proof. Wait a few moments please.

Comment: Definitely looking forward to that.

Comment: @Constantine, done (12 hours ago though). Anything else you'd like me to add?

Comment: Everything is crystal clear. Thanks, mate :)

Answer (score 2):

If you read up about [First Order Logic with Equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms), your statement follows readily using the *Substitution for formulas* axiom scheme, aka. [Leibniz' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles)